# How to properly communicate with liveview from javascript

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I'm trying to update Liveview with Javascript after a Javascript event is fired.
Liveview must show a `<div>` element with some values sent from Javascript.

My question is: how should I pass those values from Javascript to Liveview?

I might also need value sent by Liveview in Javascript. Again: how should I pass those values from Liveview to Javascript?

There is a Livesocket created in Javascript for liveview to work but I see no way to get or set assign values from there.
The only way to pass values from/to Liveview seem to be via the DOM at some point. For example:

```html
<div id="lv-data" phx-hook="JavascriptHook"></div>
```

```js
let hooks = {};
hooks.JavascriptHook = {
  mounted(){

    this.el.addEventListener("jsEvent", (e) => 
      this.pushEvent("jsEventToPhx", e.data, (reply, ref) => 
        console.log("not sure what to do here")));

    this.handleEvent("phxEventToJS", (payload) => console.log("data received: " + payload));
  }
}
```

This feel weird to have to use the DOM with a dummy `<div>` at all for pure data exchange...

Answer (score 6):

Is your `LiveView` module implemented to handle the `jsEventToPhx` event you're sending from the front-end? You must have a parent `LiveView` or `LiveViewComponent` which implements the `handle_event/3` callback for the this message. See:

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#c:handle_event/3

For example (in your LiveView module):

```elixir
def handle_event("jsEventToPhx", params, socket) do
  # Here the `params` variable is what you are sending form the
  # client-side, so it will be `%{foo: "bar"}` if you
  # follow the next example.
  {:reply, %{hello: "world"}, socket}
end
```

Then in your Hook, all you need is to use `this.pushEvent`:

```javascript
let hooks = {};
hooks.JavascriptHook = {
  mounted(){
    this.pushEvent("jsEventToPhx", {foo: "bar"}, (reply, ref) => 
     // this will print `{hello: "world"}` 
     console.log(reply)
    );
  }
}
```

This is the approach when you want to send data to LiveView and optionally receive the response immediately.

If you want to send something from `LiveView` to the client, then the process is slightly different. From LiveView you use `push_event` when returning a socket from any `handle_event` callback, for example:

```elixir
{:noreply, push_event(socket, "phxEventToJS", %{abc: "xyz"})}
```

And in your Hook, you subscribe to events:

```javascript
mounted(){
  this.pushEvent("jsEventToPhx", {foo: "bar"}, (reply, ref) => 
   // this will print `{hello: "world"}` 
   console.log(reply);
  }

  this.handleEvent("phxEventToJS", (payload) => {
    // this will print `{abc: "xyz"}`
    console.log(payload);
  }
}
```

It may be useful to check the client-server communication section [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/js-interop.html#client-server-communication).

Comment: Show the client-side javascript in a <script> tag or something that sends this event with that jsEventToPhx name, some params, and the socket. That's his question. How do we send FROM javascript TO the normal LiveView handle_event's or _infos?